# update multiple column in table using same table data in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I am trying to update a table with two column first is **marketplace_fee** and other is s**ettlment_value**,

for updating **marketplace_fee**,  need to calculate some column and

for calculate **settlment_value** need marketplace_fee.

The problem is:

When  run the update query first time it only update marketplace_fee not Settlment_value but when execute it  again then it update both column .

**Query**

```
update 
    fk_pay_cal 
set 
    marketplace_fee = (((((totalprice * commission  )/100) + shippingcharge + fixed_fee))+
            ((((totalprice * commission  )/100) + shippingcharge +
            fixed_fee)) * (service_tax) /100) ,
    settlment_value = totalprice - marketplace_fee
```

Comment: what's the ID column in your table ?

Comment: So you want to use the _new_ calculated value of `marketplace_fee` for the `settlement_value`?

Comment: there is no uniqe id

Comment: If table don't have an unique id then just try this(using [ctid](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-system-columns.html)) - http://hastebin.com/qiboqusica.avrasm

Comment: A table without a primary key? That doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bracketsfull expression can be written down in much simpler form. Use it twice in both assignments:

```
update 
    fk_pay_cal 
set 
    marketplace_fee = 
        (totalprice * commission/100 + shippingcharge + fixed_fee) * (service_tax /100+ 1),
    settlment_value = 
        totalprice 
        - (totalprice * commission/100 + shippingcharge + fixed_fee) * (service_tax /100+ 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is to do the calculation in a CTE.  This is most helpful if you have a unique id or primary key on the data:

```
with newvals as (
      select pc.*,
             (((((totalprice * commission  )/100) + shippingcharge + fixed_fee))+
            ((((totalprice * commission  )/100) + shippingcharge +
            fixed_fee)) * (service_tax) /100) as new_markeplace_fee
      from fk_pay_cal
     )
update fk_pay_cal
    set market_place_fee = new_markeplace_fee,
        settlment_value = totalprice - new_marketplace_fee
    from newvals
    where newvals.id = fk_pay_cal.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is intended. Any reference to a column on the *right* side of the assignment uses the "old" value of that column. Otherwise you couldn't do things like `update foo set x=y, y=x;`

As I guess you do not want to repeat the formula, you need to use a two step approach to update this in a single query:

```
with calculated as (
  select pk_column, 
         (((((totalprice * commission  )/100) + shippingcharge + fixed_fee))+
            ((((totalprice * commission  )/100) + shippingcharge +
            fixed_fee)) * (service_tax) /100) as marketing_fee
  from fk_pay_cal 
  where pk_column = ... --<< make sure you only select those that you want to change
) 
update fk_pay_cal 
  set marketplace_fee = c.marketplace_fee,
     settlment_value = totalprice - c.marketplace_fee
from calculated c 
where c.pk_column = fk_pay_cal.pk_column;
```

You need to replace `pk_column` with the real name of the primary key column of your table.

**Edit** if you do not have a primary key (why?) then replace `pk_column` with `ctid` which is an internal identifier for a row that can be used in a situation like this (but it is ***not*** suitable as a general replacement for a primary key)

If you intend to update **all** rows in the table, then of course you need to remove the `where` clause inside the CTE.

---

Another option (which might be better in the long run anyway) is to create a function that encapsulates this formula:

```
create or replace function calc_fee(p_pay fk_pay_cal) 
  returns numeric
as
$$
  select (((((p_pay.totalprice * p_pay.commission) / 100) + p_pay.shippingcharge + p_pay.fixed_fee)) 
 + ((((p_pay.totalprice * p_pay.commission  )/100) + p_pay.shippingcharge + p_pay.fixed_fee)) * (p_pay.service_tax) /100);
$$
language sql
stable;
```

Then you can use that function in the update statement:

```
update fk_pay_cal 
  set marketplace_fee  = calc_fee(fk_pay_cal), 
      settlment_value = totalprice - calc_fee(fk_pay_cal);
```

As the function is declared `stable` Postgres will only call it once per row.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `ID` is the PK column

```
   with cte (
          update 
    fk_pay_cal 
set 
    marketplace_fee = (((((totalprice * commission  )/100) + shippingcharge + fixed_fee))+
            ((((totalprice * commission  )/100) + shippingcharge +
            fixed_fee)) * (service_tax) /100) 
    returning marketplace_fee,id)
    )
   update 
    fk_pay_cal set settlment_value = cte.marketplace_fee  from cte where cte.id=fk_pay_cal.id
```

---

or using [`ctid`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-system-columns.html)

```
 with cte (
          update 
    fk_pay_cal 
set 
    marketplace_fee = (((((totalprice * commission  )/100) + shippingcharge + fixed_fee))+
            ((((totalprice * commission  )/100) + shippingcharge +
            fixed_fee)) * (service_tax) /100) 
    returning marketplace_fee,ctid)
    )
   update 
    fk_pay_cal set settlment_value = cte.marketplace_fee  from cte where cte.ctid=fk_pay_cal.ctid
```